# javascript based ad does not show up on production machine

Tags: javascript, django, html

I am encountering a rather strange problem to which I am not able to find a solution to.. So, I have an ad I display using the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://media.mycoolad.com/ad.aspx?id=2723"></script>
```

on my development machine (running django) - the ad shows up fine on chrome. on my production machine (again running django) - the ad does not show up in both firefox and chrome. The only thing I can think of (in terms of difference between dev and prod machine) is that in prod I have https configured and opbviously, this is not on my local dev.

I am unsure how to debug this issue :( and was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction..

Comment: Check JS console for any errors/output - that might explain the situation.

Comment: Do you have an ad blocker installed? :) [insert evil laugh here]

Comment: Your browser developer tools should make it possible to track what HTTP requests are being made, and what the responses are. You should be able to tell if that `<script>` element is being included just by looking at the HTML of the page; if not, then the problem is in your server somewhere.

Comment: @Topsitemakers: on my JS console I see it says that `the page at https://xx.com ran insecure content from http://media.mycoolad.com/ad.aspx?id=2723` Any clues on how I can solve this? :(

Comment: You need to run the ad from https aka `src="//media.mycoolad.com/ad.aspx?id=2723"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing url of ad to:

```
https://media.mycoolad.com/ad.aspx?id=2723
```

Or try to provide a non-specific protocol URL so the browser can choose to load http or https:

```
//media.mycoolad.com/ad.aspx?id=2723
```

Answer (score 0):

Load the ad using an HTTPS link rather than an HTTP link and it will work, it happens the same thing with css files or images.

or as @Jotakun said, use the protocol of the parent page, change https or http to '//'.